# Routes in vue with pregenerated templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to call a function that does some internal stuff and generates some html. I do want to call this function when I load my Vue Router, but I always get an error.  Here is my Code:

```
    const Route = { template: loadHtml() };
    // ...

    const routes = {
        '/': Home,
        // ...
    };

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '.container',
        data: {
            currentRoute: window.location.pathname,
            // ...
        },
        computed: {
            ViewComponent () {
                return routes[this.currentRoute]
            }
        },
        render (h) { return h(this.ViewComponent) }
    });
```

Please note that I am a beginner in Vue. The Error that I get is:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

Comment: How are you including vue.js?  are you using the version that includes the compiler?

Comment: I am including vue.js via <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>.